# Carthage install of Eureka failing due to Swift Version

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

Starting with a brand new project, I am trying to install [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) through Carthage.  I set up a Cartfile with the specified line: `github "xmartlabs/Eureka" ~> 3.0.0` as instructed.

I then execute with:  `carthage update --platform iOS`

The build fails with the message:

> Task failed with exit code 65" with the further message that the
>   project likely failed to compile.  Checking the log file as instructed
>   I see the following: "error: SWIFT_VERSION '3.0' is unsupported,
>   supported versions are: 4.0, 4.2, 5.0. (in target 'Eureka')

I am using Xcode 10.2.1 and the new project defaults Swift Compiler Language  to Swift 5.  However, this is for the target of the new project.  I see in the error the version is 3.0 for target Eureka.

Do I need to change something else for the default running through the terminal?  Do I have some old version of a setting from Swift 3.0 hanging around somewhere?

Comment: Why are you declaring that you need version 3.0.0 of Eureka? If you're using top version of Swift you can't use this outdated version of the lib.

Comment: Eurekas page states that you should use version `5.0` instead of  `3.0`. Try using `github "xmartlabs/Eureka" ~> 5.0` instead. You can see all releases and their changelogs [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/releases). Xcode 10.2.1 only supports Swift versions `>4.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, version Eureka 5.0 solved it.  Unfortunately I was using the command from the webpage https://eurekacommunity.github.io/"github which says use:  "xmartlabs/Eureka" ~> 3.0.0"

Comment: `Copyright 2012-2017 © Xmartlabs.` — it's outdated for two years.